# python run CMD command with options

Tags: python, cmd, system

This is frustrating. I searched  about it a lot but none of the results help me. I tried subprocess but I still cant get it to work. Basically I want to get this line to work:

```
appName = "ap01"
optna = "-server"
optnb = "-filename=c:/test.VS"
optnc = "-display=1"

os.system('start "VSM" "C:/bin/" {appName, optna, optnb, optnc} ')
```

In CMD I would simply type

```
CD C:/bin/
```

press enter and then:

```
ap01 -server -filename=C:/test.VS -display=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
import os

appName = "ap01"
opts =[
    "-server",
    "-filename=c:/test.VS",
    "-display=1"
]

opts = ' '.join(opts)
os.system(r'start "" "C:\bin\{:}" {:}'.format(appName, opts) )
```

hard to test since i dont have ap01 but works with a simple batch file. Anyway you should use sub process just like @l4mpi comments. So that would do is:

```
import subprocess
import os

app=[
    "ap01.ext",
    "-server",
    "-filename=c:/test.VS",
    "-display=1"
]

os.chdir('"C:/bin/')
subprocess.call(app, shell=True)
```

Note this is a bit pickier on windows since it needs to know the FULL name of your application. As for weather or not the app can be terminated via esc depends a bit on the nature of ap01. If you run it via a shell the yes it would be terminable, since the shell lives on and can be terminated. If you pipe it then it may or may not. You should probably launch and convert it as a service with **INSTSRV.EXE**

Comment: Heya, works like a charm ! Just 1 question. If I run my program from CMD the only way to cancel it is if I use ctrl+C. Now if I run it from python if I press ESC it cancels it too. Is there a way so that ESC will NOT cancel my program? One of reasons why i write GUI for that app is so that I keep on canceling it accidentally every time I press esc in windows :(

Comment: How about no? There's no reason to use `os.system` after python2.4, `Popen` / `subprocess.call` should be preferred; especially in this case since you can just set the working directory with the `cwd` argument.

Comment: @l4mpi I agree but that's what the user was using and didn't have time to do further (no python above 2.3 at hand) because things just happen :P Anyway ill revise it now that i have time again.

Comment: Heya @l4mpi sorry for asking for system it was simply the method I was most successful about... I tried with popen after ur commend and I did managed to get it to work using this line :
       `code output = Popen(['C:/bin/ap01', scenefile,imgfile,display,verb,prog,progPerc], stdout=PIPE)
        print output.stdout.read()` However once I plug that in to my QT window I don't get progress detail any more(before I got it from CMD window) and esc still cancel my calculations :( @joojaa thanks a lot for both of codes! They all works and helped me understand it a lot more!